# Can Flask session data be altered by users (threat actors)?

Tags: python, session, flask

I [watched a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhcnBTDLxCI) of a person decode a Flask session and access the data, and I think it's been said before not to store secrets in Sessions, but what if I want to store a role, say `"admin": False` which grants UI access to front end admin buttons

```
{% if session.admin %}
    <button>Delete website</button>
{% endif %}
```

Are users able to alter session data at all and override server settings?

```
"admin": True # uh oh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although Flask session contents can be seen by anyone who knows how to decode base64, user can't simply modify its contents by setting desired values and puting them back base64-encoded in session because of integrity signature you can hear about at https://youtu.be/mhcnBTDLxCI?t=339.

The signature itself is generated based on session contents and app secret which is visible only on server side. So the user won't be able to tamper with session's contents successfully because he doesn't know the key set in `SECRET_KEY` in application settings.

So answering your question: you can store such admin flag in session and it will not be a threat to security provided your secret key is random enough [Flask session doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions) and not disclosed to anyone.